# Can a malware steal the content of the clipboard?

Tags: malware

Is there any malware that can steal the content of the clipboard?.

E.g. say you have a text file with say private info or passwords, and you copy this data to paste on say another text file on a flash drive. Are there any malware that can get that copied data and transmit it over the net ?

Comment: I don't know if there actually are viruses that do this, but it is certainly possible. If a virus can control your system, it can make use of the clipboard, and send the data over the internet.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. It can be done with Javascript too. The beef-xss toolkit has an attack which facilitates this. https://github.com/beefproject/beef/tree/master/modules/host/clipboard_theft

Comment: Don't forget the disagreeable [Tynt Tracer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203082/injecting-text-when-content-is-copied-from-a-web-page).